# Do we need to do anything on server side in order to supporting Chrome's SPDY?

Tags: http, spdy

Google's SPDY has been deployed to Chrome 18. It is awesome! It makes web much faster!

So my question is:

If I wanna let my website can support SPDY, do I need to do anything on my server side (E.g. Changing some server's settings)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a web server that supports it. Like:

- Jetty
- node-spdy
- Apache + mod_spdy
- …

See the SPDY project for more informations: http://dev.chromium.org/spdy and of course, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY#Server_support_and_usage).